# How to call nodejs code from android java code?

Tags: android, node.js

I have a cross-platform app which use nodejs, corvoda, angular etc.

Now I would like to use native android code to re-write the ui related code. for the logic/model part, I still want use the nodejs code.

After google and did not find way to finish this.

How can I call nodejs code from android code.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you have designed you app properly then you should be using using node.js as a rest server and angularJs as client.

If you have exposed all the APIs correctly and there is no dependency between the server and the client then you can replace the angularJs with any other client.

Your android code will make the http request to the server and will get the same response. The only thing which would change on the client side is code syntax and structure. Code logic should remain the same.

Comment: The nodejs code also stay in the same android device as UI code.

Comment: That's really not what the question is about. It's about when you want to do the same thing in your app as what you're doing in node.